# jQuery - register click on html5 video play button

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to register click on the play button of a html5 video. I can register click on the `<video>` tag but any click on the controls (play/pause etc) is not registered. How can I register those clicks?

I tried using:

```
$('video').prop('controls').click(function() { });
```

but that didn't work.

Here is a [fiddle][1].

```js
$(function() {


     $('video').click( function() {
          $('#info').append('clicked video' + '<br/>');
 
     });

  //non working:
   /*  $('video').prop('controls').click(function() {
    
      $('#info').append('clicked video controls' + '<br/>');
    
    }); */
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="100%" controls onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();" playsinline>  
  <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" 
          type="video/mp4" 
    >
   <script>
     var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
     video.volume = 0.1;
    </script>
</video>

<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controling HTML5 video with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523240/controling-html5-video-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `play` and `pause` event of video

```js
$('video').on("play pause", function() {
  $('#info').append('clicked video' + '<br/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="250" controls onclick="this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();" playsinline>  
  <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe it could work... but this registeres when the video plays and pauses - so since I have a "play()" event starting when clicking on the video, those clicks will also be registered with on("play pause"). So it doesn't register the click on the controls, it registers the play/pause event.

Comment: That "play pause" solution will work for me, so I'll mark it as solved, thanks!